# text color on a plot no longer works

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have the following plotshape statements that go on the candlestick chart. They worked great until a couple of months ago. Initially the color of the text would match the color of the triangle, but now the triangle is the right color , but the text is a neon dark blue, very hard to see.

```
plotshape(TTM_To_Buy and not TTM_To_Buy[1], title='Slope Positive', location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.lime, 0), style=shape.triangleup, text='BUY' )
plotshape(TTM_To_Sell and not TTM_To_Sell[1], title='Slope Negative', location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.yellow, 0), style=shape.triangledown, text='SELL')
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend that you define the `textcolor` in the `plotshape()` function.

Example code:

```
plotshape(TTM_To_Buy and not TTM_To_Buy[1], 
            title='Slope Positive', 
            location=location.belowbar,
            color=color.new(color.lime, 0), 
            style=shape.triangleup, 
            text='BUY',
            textcolor = color.new(color.lime, 0)
            )
```